# Python id of function of instance is inconsistent

Tags: python, binding, closures

Please consider the following

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass


a = A()
# accessing a's foo seems consistent
init1 = a.foo
init2 = a.foo
assert init1 == init2
assert id(a.foo) == id(a.foo)

# Or is it?
foos= [a.foo for i in range(10)]
ids = [id(foo) for foo in foos]
for i, id_ in enumerate(ids):
    for j, id__ in enumerate(ids):
        if i != j:
            assert id_ != id__
```

It appears `id(a.foo)` can equal to `id(a.foo)` and can not equal to `id(a.foo)`, but I can't understand when it is the same and when it isn't.

Please explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transformation of a function to an instance method happens every time the instance method attribute is accessed, so the id should be different every time, at least in the sense that a new object has been created. (see [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for details about method transformation and descriptors)

The problem is doing this:

```
assert id(a.foo) == id(a.foo)
```

There are times the Python garbage collector can work so fast that even within a single expression, two different objects can have the same id, because the object has already been reclaimed once `id()` is done with it.

If you do this:

```
assert id(init1) == id(init2)
```

you'll see that they in fact have different ids.

---

Update: to address the question about why `init1 == init2` is `True`: `init1` and `init2` are method wrapper objects that refer to the same function in the same class, so the method wrapper's `__eq__()` considers them equal.

Comment: I've been using Python for 25 years and have no idea what this means: *"The transformation of a function to an instance method happens"*

Comment: @PeterWood: It's in the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html): "Note that the transformation from function object to instance method object happens each time the attribute is retrieved from the instance."

Comment: @PeterWood `instance.function` is actually equivalent to `type(instance).function.__get__(instance)`, where the conversion from function to method is completed.

Comment: @MechanicPig Where are the docs about that? In fact, this is intended to make [your recent answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73918275/913098) work

Comment: @sj95126 What is the logic behind binding the method on each access? Where does that happen? in `getattr` of `object`?

Comment: Also, why is `init1==init2` not the same as `id(init1)==id(init2)`?

Comment: @Gulzar: Binding on each access is just the way Python does it. Method access is implemented using descriptors (described in the Data Model).

Comment: @Gulzar: I added an update about `init1 == init2`.

Answer (score -1):

**Note that the 2 `id` of the same `id` is not the same value**:

for example:

```
a = 1 
b =1

print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(a))
```

will give me this result:

```
9788992
9788992
9788992
```

but

```
print(id(id(a)))
print(id(id(a)))
```

will give this:

```
140331099421680
140331099421648
```

`foos= [a.foo for i in range(10)]` gives the same `id` valou to each one.

But the `id` of the id's in `foos` is not the same value.

Therefore:

```
ids = [id(foo) for foo in foos]
```

Gives different values to each one.

Comment: I didn't use `id(id(...)` anywhere in the question

Comment: enumerate(ids) gives 2 instances with different ID's and the same value.

Comment: @MichaelMulvey right. I made a mistake:)

Comment: @MichaelMulvey Why really the `id` of the `id` is not the same. Even if the first `id` is the same?

Answer (score -1):

assert id(a.foo) is a type, not a number or variable.

each instance has a unique ID  so ID of a.foo does not equal ID of a.foo's second instance. You are looking for a boolean variable.(True/False)

So basically you are comparing something like the following:

```
# First instance (object in memory)
a.foo == building 1 apt 1
#second instance (object in memory)
a.foo ==building 1 apt 1

a.foo == a.foo  # boolean value "True"

# First instance of ID a.foo 
id(a.foo) == building 1 apt 1
# Second instance of ID a.foo
id(a.foo) == building 2 apt 1

id(a.foo) == id(a.foo) Boolean value "False".
```

While the above example is not technically correct. It gives you a better understanding of what is going on. What actually is happening is instance a.foo #1 gives a memory location and a.foo # 2 gives another memory location and even though the two values are the same the location in memory is not.

I hope this helps clarify things a bit for you.

Try this. add the following code to the end of your script:

```
 print(a)

 print(id(a))
```

Now run it 2 times. The ID's change. and the memory location does too.

Comment: This makes no sense, and doesn't explain WHY a.foo returns something different on each call. The accepted answer explained it well enough.